# How to add retry in MongoDb C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, sockets, mongodb-.net-driver, networkstream

Sometimes the `ReceiveBufferAsync` in `Find` method throws:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I think it could be fixed with something like a retry in that method:

```
mongodb.driver.core\core\connections\binaryconnection.cs

private async Task<IByteBuffer> ReceiveBufferAsync()
{
            try
            {
                var messageSizeBytes = new byte[4];
                await _stream.ReadBytesAsync(messageSizeBytes, 0, 4, _backgroundTaskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var messageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(messageSizeBytes, 0);
                var inputBufferChunkSource = new InputBufferChunkSource(BsonChunkPool.Default);
                var buffer = ByteBufferFactory.Create(inputBufferChunkSource, messageSize);
                buffer.Length = messageSize;
                buffer.SetBytes(0, messageSizeBytes, 0, 4);
                await _stream.ReadBytesAsync(buffer, 4, messageSize - 4, _backgroundTaskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                _lastUsedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                buffer.MakeReadOnly();
                return buffer;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var wrappedException = WrapException(ex, "receiving a message from the server");
                ConnectionFailed(wrappedException);
                throw wrappedException;
            }
}
```

But I can't find the way. Get a new stream here?

Comment: I would think this would be best as a discussion on github,  or perhaps to open up a Jira issue with them

Comment: @runxc1BretFerrier I wrote to the few days ago to driver's creator I hope he could take a look at this. For now I reduced keep alive time to 120 as is adviced in MongoDB on Azure

Comment: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly